# Understanding Javascript loop with setTimeout

Tags: javascript, settimeout

Why this function returns junk value followed by 5 5s

```
for (var j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        console.log(j);
    }, 1000);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The returned value is returned from [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout). It is not junk value, it is the id of the timeout.

> timeoutID is the numerical ID of the timeout, which can be used later with window.clearTimeout().

This id associated with `timeout` is used when clearing the timeout.

```
var timeoutID = setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('hello');
}, 1000);

clearTimeout(timeoutID);
```

Another problem in your code is that it'll always print `5` in console. Because, the time when the setTimeout callback is executed, the loop is already executed and the value of `j` is `5`.

To solve this use *closure* inside the loop.

```js
for (var j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
  (function(j) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      document.write(j + '<br />');
    }, 1000);
  }(j));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The observed behavior is as desired. You can update your code to following

```
for(var j=0;j<5;j++){
  (function(index){
    setTimeout(function(){console.log(index);},1000);
  })(j);
}
```

The above paints the expected/correct values i.e. 0,1,2,3,4

As per question, all the timeout functions are sharing a common variable j, hence, when the first logging was done, till then j was already updated to 5.

So, you need to make sure you have private copies for each timeout function. Hence, in order to achieve the expected/correct values, you need to use closures.

Comment: But what's reason for above function returning junk data?